# Do the member and memberOf fields in Active Directory get updated when object in its value is deleted?

Tags: python, linux, active-directory

I am fetching AD data via ldap3 connections to domain controllers using python.
One group has many users in member field.
But, when I search the users directly, few of them have no entry.

Hence, my question is as below.
If a group object is deleted, does it get removed from the member field of its parent group and `memberOf` field of its user?
And, if a user object is deleted, does it get removed from the member field of its parent group?

Note:
I am checking all available domain controllers and looking for latest entry of any object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as the user and group is in the same AD forest, then the user is removed from the groups when the user is deleted.

The only exception is users on an external, trusted domain.

If you update your question with your code, we might be able to spot something wrong.